# Symfony & FOSUserBundle. Customize validation errors on register template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I was trying to solve my problem: I'm not able to find where the validation errors of `register_content.html.twig` are defined.

I need to know how to show that errors as I would like. Nowadays my Register is looks like:

[image]

As you can see, there is a ugly validation error. I want to change the tags

```
<div>
 <ul><li> Las dos contraseñas no coinciden. </li></ul> 
</div>
```

predefined somewhere, by another.

I have overridden the view **register_content.html.twig** and I can to show that validation errors but not customize it.

```
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
</div>
```

Do you know how I can customize HTML structure of the validation errors?

**For example** in `login_content.html.twig` the validation errors are shown like this:

[image]

It is possible because in `login_content.html.twig` are defined the validation errors:

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I have change the `{{ form_error }}` variable in Twig for `form.field.vars.errors`.

An example, If you want to customize your email validation errors:

```
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
</div>
```

change it by:

```
{% for errorItem in form.email.vars.errors %}
    <div>{{ errorItem.message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

You could use a **div** tag or whatever tag you want.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override the default symfony form error block.
You can find out how to do it in the symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#customizing-error-output)

you will be able to set this form theme globaly or per view as shown in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations)

So for example if you would like to display the errors inside a div with a class `alert alert-danger` you would create a file `views/Form/form_errors.html.twig`

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{# form_errors.html.twig #}
{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
            {% for error in errors %}
                <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

and to use this custom theme just in the registration form you would call at the top of your override file `register_content.html.twig`

```
{% form_theme form 'Form/form_errors.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Hi Knetsi, thanks for your answer. I have found other more simply method to customize that. Anyway I have checked that If I use only `error` tag in a view It appears on the debug  "Variable "error" does not exist.
500 Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [translation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html). In parameters.ini [set locale](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html#the-translation-process) to your language and create [message file](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html#translation-locations-and-naming-conventions). Then in twig template use:

```
    {% if error %}
        <div class="error">{{ error.message|trans({},'messages') }}</div>
    {% endif %}
```

Another solution would be:

```
{{ error.message | replace({"Bad credentials." : "Invalid username or password."}) }}
```

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for. Thanks anyway.