# Customize form error symfony 4

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

In Symfony 4, when you do something like that:

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.something) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.something) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.something) }}
</div>
```

The following is shown:

```
<div>
    <label for="form_something">Something</label>
    <ul>
        <li>This field is required</li>
        <li>Another error</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="form_something" name="form[something]" />
</div>
```

I would like to be able to customize the way in which errors are displayed.

Instead of being shown this way:

```
<ul>
    <li>This field is required</li>
    <li>Another error</li>
</ul>
```

I would like it to be this way:

```
<div class="form-control-feedback">This field is required</div>
<div class="form-control-feedback">Another error</div>
```

Y read this page [How to Customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) but I can not understand how it works.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I have answered a question about overriding a form template already, you can see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279247/5064866 , in your case you can set the theme you will create globaly, i provided link to documentation in the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#customizing-error-output) describes how you can configure errors output globally

You render it using

```
{% form_theme form 'form/form_errors.html.twig' %}

{# ... #}
{{ form_errors(form.something) }}
```

File `form/form_errors.html.twig`

```
{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
          {% for error in errors %}
                <div class="form-control-feedback">{{ error.message }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: {% form_theme form 'form/form_errors.html.twig' %} is correct.

The brackets are syntax error. They are only for multiple templates - https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#multiple-templates

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<div class="form">
    <label class="control-label">{{ form_label(form.something) }}</label>
    {{ form_widget(form.something, { 'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
    {% if form.something.vars['errors']|length > 0 %}
        <ul class="message">
            {% for error in form.something.vars['errors'] %}
                <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Review the entire code, you will find some answers for your questions.

Each properties or fields of a form has a `vars` attribute, this store some data, including the `['errors']` which contains all errors after you submit the form. You can retrieve this data and show the error separately.

The link [Form Rendering Customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) is related to how to customize the templates of the forms in your system.